# Get image summary with Wikidata SPARQL

Tags: sparql, wikidata, wikimedia-commons, wdqs

I get some images from Wikidata, but I would like to get more information about the image.

By example, I get the image from Paris ([Try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3FitemLabel%20%3FwdLabel%20%3Fps_Label%20%3FwdpqLabel%20%3Fpq_Label%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20VALUES%20%3Fitem%20%7B%20wd%3AQ90%20%7D%20%23%20Paris%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20p%3AP18%20%3Fstatement.%0A%20%20%3Fstatement%20%3Fps%20%3Fps_.%0A%20%20%3Fwd%20wikibase%3Aclaim%20%3Fp%3B%0A%20%20%20%20wikibase%3AstatementProperty%20%3Fps.%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fstatement%20%3Fpq%20%3Fpq_.%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fwdpq%20wikibase%3Aqualifier%20%3Fpq.%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%7D)):

```sql
SELECT ?itemLabel ?wdLabel ?ps_Label ?wdpqLabel ?pq_Label WHERE {
  VALUES ?item { wd:Q90 }
  ?item p:P18 ?statement.
  ?statement ?ps ?ps_.
  ?wd wikibase:claim ?p;
    wikibase:statementProperty ?ps.
  OPTIONAL {
    ?statement ?pq ?pq_.
    ?wdpq wikibase:qualifier ?pq.
  }
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
```

Giving me the following result:

[image]

But I would like to retrieve additional data, as we can see on [Wikidata page](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q90#q90$B681A1D1-2BEE-4BA2-8B9A-F776A30E0100):

- Dimension: "4,114 x 4,235"
- Size: "9.07 MB"

And also data from the [File summary](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Paris_-_Eiffelturm_und_Marsfeld2.jpg#Summary):

- Description: "Paris : La Tour Eiffel et le Champ de Mars."
- Date: "October 2010"
- Source: "Own work"
- Author: "Wladyslaw (Taxiarchos228)"
- Etc...

**Is any way to do that with SPARQL?**

Comment: I think the image data is just part of the JPG file itself, at least file size and dimension are inherently part of it in the JPG meta data

Comment: @UninformedUser Maybe Wikidata store this data somewhere. I could load images with Javascript to get size or dimension... but I don't want to do that. If Wikidata store this data, I would like to know if it is possible to get them by requesting the SPARQL service.

Comment: ok, yeah - @StanislavKralin provided the answer. This data is not part of the RDF data but can be retrieved from an external service, which can be called via SPARQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three aproaches:

1. [MWAPI](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikidata_Query_Service/User_Manual/MWAPI#Get_imageinfo_via_Allpages_generator)
2. [Mediainfo](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format#MediaInfo_(beta))
3. [WCQS](https://wcqs-beta.wmflabs.org/)

Unfortunately, WDQS doesn't allow federation to WCQS, but the opposite is possible.

Comment: good answer. By the way, there is even a Linked Dataset about images of Wikimedia Commons: http://imgpedia.dcc.uchile.cl/ - indeed with [SPARQL endpoint](http://imgpedia.dcc.uchile.cl/query) but also with an [interactive browser](http://imgpedia.dcc.uchile.cl/detail/All_Gizah_Pyramids.jpg) - they also have some kind of "distance" measure between the image descriptors it looks like. I have to keep that in mind for fun stuff maybe